# How to hide map pins by tapping an option in the menu?

Tags: android

I am creating an app which displays several pins which have different categories according to colour, similar to displaying hotels, restaurants etc. I have a menu which when I select the option I want to hide that particular category but I am having trouble hiding the pins, I'm just not sure what code to use for this.

I've tried to use setVisibility(invisible) but I don't know where this should go.

This is within my main activity - the menu.

```
public class AR_MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        //trying to get the menu options to do something
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.poi1:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Enemy Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.poi2:
                Toast.makeText(this, "IED Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.poi3:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Obstruction Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
```

This is where the map pins are created, also within main activity.

```
  public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

       LocationManager and listener
        locationManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
                // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
                LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                mMap.clear();
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation).title("AR Projects HQ")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLocation, 16));


                LatLng obstruction = new LatLng(50.878640, -2.108940);
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(obstruction).title("Obstruction").snippet("Fallen Power Lines. Eng notified.")
                   .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE)));
```

The program runs no problem and displays a toast to display which option has been selected.

Answer (score 0):

set varible to  `mMap.addMarker`

```
Marker mark = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions() ....
mark.setVisible(false);
```

this Marker can add to array if you want

```
List<Marker> markList = new ArrayList<>();
```

////

```
Marker mark = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions() ....
markList.add(mark);
```

//// and then you can hide with loop

```
for (Marker miaw : markList) {
   miaw.setVisible(false);
}
```

Comment: How do i change the visibility of the marker pin through the menu option within the app?  This is some code from my menu.xml file.  ```<item
        android:id="@+id/poi"
        android:title="POI">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/poi1"
                android:title="Enemy" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/poi2"
                android:checkable="false"
                android:title="IED" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/poi3"
                android:title="Obstruction" />
        </menu>
    </item>

Comment: you can create multiple list of the object marker,
example :
List<Marker> markPOI = new ArrayList<>();

List<Marker> markEnemy = new ArrayList<>();

List<Marker> markIED = new ArrayList<>();